# Why sql query extract other info

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

I want get city attribute from my database. But when I run my code I get this info `(u'Rome',)`
I want get only `Rome` as result

This is my code

```
 connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                        host="",
                        database="",
                        user="",
                         passwd="")

        mycursor = connection.cursor()
        mycursor.execute ("SELECT City FROM home limit 1")
        myresult=mycursor.fetchall()

        for res in myresult:
                print res
```

Why do I get this `(u'Rome',)` result and not only `Rome`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `record` in the returned list is represented by a `tuple` even if There is only one `column`, to access the column use its index:

```
for res in myresult:
                print res[0]
```

Or unpack the tuple to variables:

```
for (city,) in myresult:
                print city
```